# what is the difference between CookieAuthenticator and SessionAuthenticator in Silhouette

Tags: silhouette

I suppose Cookie based authentication is - a server creating an id which is difficult to guess and sending it to client in a cookie. The client would then send the id to server in each request in a cookie. This also creates a session I suppose.

Question 1 - Does `CookieAuthenticator` in `Silhouette` works like this? The `CookieAuthenticatorSettings` case class also allows defining the different properties of such a cookie.

```
case class CookieAuthenticatorSettings(
  cookieName: String = "id",
  cookiePath: String = "/",
  cookieDomain: Option[String] = None,
  secureCookie: Boolean = true,
  httpOnlyCookie: Boolean = true,
  useFingerprinting: Boolean = true,
  cookieMaxAge: Option[FiniteDuration] = None,
  authenticatorIdleTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration] = None,
  authenticatorExpiry: FiniteDuration = 12 hours)
```

Question2 - If Cookie authentication creates a session, what is `SessionAuthenticator` and how it works? How is it different from `CookieAuthenticator`?